# Having to Submit Twice

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, session-variables

Ok I am new to programming and I have an issue with some checkboxes.
I want to store if a check box is checked and display this when button is pressed.
I am making a filter search, so when a person selects a check box it will only display that filter.
However it only works if I submit and select or deselect a checkbox twice.
How can I make it to only have to do this once?

```
<form name="search" action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkAllMyCB" id="checkAllMyCB" onclick="jqCheckAll2( this.id, 'myCB' )"/>All
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("art", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="art">Art
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("church", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="church">Church
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("education", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="education">Education/Schools
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("food", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="food">Food
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("gardening", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="gardening">Gardening
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("kids", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="kids">Kids
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("music", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="music">Music
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("outdoors", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="outdoors">Outdoors
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("seniors", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="seniors">Seniors
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("sports", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="sports">Sports/Physical Activity
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <? if (in_array("support", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="support">Club/Support Group
   <input type="submit" name="Go2" id="Go2" value="Go &gt;" />
<? 
$_SESSION['category'] = $_POST['category']; ?>

</form>
```

Comment: If you want your sentences on separate lines, put two spaces at the end of each line. I edited that for you since that's what you had in your source. If you wanted it all in one paragraph without line breaks, feel free to change it back.

Comment: No problem, thank you. You also have a run-on sentence in your second line. I don't quite understand it as it's written - perhaps you could split it into two or rephrase? (I would do it myself, but StackOverflow doesn't accept edits that small.)

Comment: Thanks, English is my 5th language so I am sorry for typos or run-on. I grew up in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two** things are wrong in your code:

1. You are first displaying the form and then setting values into the `SESSION`. This should be the opposite way because when submitted, your form would be displayed first and only after the values would get set which is why you have the problem of submitting it twice to see the values.
2. You are not checking whether the `SESSION` variable has been set before the `in_array`, this would throw an error initially. The same case with `$_POST['category']`

First place this on top:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['category'])){
$_SESSION['category'] = $_POST['category']; }
else
{
    unset($_SESSION['category']);
}
?>
```

Then change your form code to:

```
<form name="search" action="" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkAllMyCB" id="checkAllMyCB" onclick="jqCheckAll2( this.id, 'myCB' )"/>All
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("art", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="art">Art
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("church", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="church">Church
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("education", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="education">Education/Schools
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("food", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="food">Food
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("gardening", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?>value="gardening">Gardening
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("kids", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="kids">Kids
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("music", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="music">Music
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("outdoors", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="outdoors">Outdoors
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("seniors", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="seniors">Seniors
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("sports", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="sports">Sports/Physical Activity
   <input name="category[]" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['category']) && in_array("support", $_SESSION['category'])) { echo "checked='checked'";  } ?> value="support">Club/Support Group
   <input type="submit" name="Go2" id="Go2" value="Go &gt;" />
</form>
```

Comment: I want to thank you so very much for the great help.

Comment: @user3325732 My bad, I just realized this code can be shortened (by skipping the `!empty($_SESSION['category'])` check) by unsetting the SESSION instead of making it empty, you might want to use this instead.

Comment: Thanks @I Can Has Cheezburger